# How do you route Vue layouts in Laravel (MPA)

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes

I have just started working with Laravel after four months of using CodeIgniter. I do like Laravels way of doing things but I'm still rather clueless about Laravels implementation of VueJS.

I have set up my router

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index'); [etc..]
```

and I have successfully implemented the example (renamed it to MyButton.vue)

```
<body>
        @extends('layouts.app')

        @section('content')
        <my-button name="button" text="{{ $text }}"></my-button>
        <my-button text="{{ $text }}"></my-button>

        @endsection
</body>
```

Now I wonder how to use the Laravel view with Vue. Here is the standart structure:

```
resources/
├── js/
│   ├── components/
│   │   ├── MyButton.vue 
│   │   └── ...   
│   │
│   ├── app.js
│   └── bootstrap.js
│   
└── views/
    ├── layouts/
    │   └──app.blade.php
    ├── welcome.blade.php
    ├── ...
```

Do I now create a new file in layouts/ for every new page and have one in views/? Or do I do it the other way round?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

No just create a views folder under the resources/js folder.

Then setup an app.js file. Check this link out for full instructions https://gist.github.com/ratiw/a04b7eb9a2c80b9c950b